# installing compass on mac issue

Tags: ruby, macos, sass, compass-sass

I am installing compass on mac. when I run `gem install compass` command on terminal I got following output

[image]

I already have ruby `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]` installed. I got this output after issuing `ruby -v` command on terminal.

How can fix above problems or how can I install compass successfully?

Comment: I edited your tags. Where Compass is a tool for CSS, this is not a CSS question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you should be a root to install gems when using ruby from system.
It is a very good idea to run ruby with rvm or similar tools instead of running
system.